# Is it possible to set the exact size of a window?

Tags: macos

For the purpose of recording some scenario on my screen in 720 HD format, I would like to set the window of a particular application to the exact size of 1280x720 pixels. With some patience, I  managed to resize it manually to the required size. Is there a better way to achieve this? I am on MountainLion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no inbuilt functionality in Mountain Lion to do this.

I use an application called [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) which allows you to do what you're asking. Here is part of the preferences dialog:

[image]

It's also handy for stretching windows fullscreen, unlike the green icon on the top left of each window, which behaves differently per app!